# ggplot2 bar chart gives weird y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data that looks like this:

```
iv <- as.factor(c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y"))
dv <- as.numeric(as.character(c(3,35,23,53,24,34,43,23)))
```

When I use ggplot2, using this code:

```
chart <- data.frame(iv,dv)
ggplot(chart, aes(x=iv, y=dv)) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

the bar plot has y-axis that does not correspond with my dv

May I know what did I do wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that you see are the sum of all `dv` values for each `iv`.

```
tapply(dv, iv, sum)
#  x   y 
#114 124
```

Maybe one of these plots is what you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

chart %>%
  group_by(iv) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=iv, y=dv, fill = factor(row))) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```
chart %>%
  group_by(iv) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=iv, y=dv, fill = factor(row))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]